# HDMI ground loop from gaming PC to AVR

Tags: avr, troubleshooting, ground-loop, hdmi, pc

I have a ground loop from my HDMI from gaming PC to AVR. It's very annoying.
Aside from getting an expensive ground loop isolation transformer for 1000 W, is there any other way?

Is there an HDMI cable or adaptor that breaks the ground in the cables?

Is there a fiber HDMI cable that does not have copper between the cable for ARC support?

Is there an HDMI ground loop eliminator adaptor I can buy?

From what I can tell none of these things exist. If anyone can help me figure this out, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Question is unclear, you say you have an annoying ground loop, but what does it do then? You seem to want to solve this by asking what to buy which is off-topic. For all we know, your ground loop might just be a result of using ungrounded mains socket for equipment that needs a grounded mains socket.

Comment: You can attempt to break the ground and possibly power of an HDMI cable and see if it works still.  Spend on cable, meter, and a blade.  How are you so certain that a ground loop exists?  If you know where it is, you can try to make there be no current/EMI that affects the loop.

Comment: Ah yes, so this is an apartment, so nothing I can do there. Issue does not exist outside of gaming PC being connected to HDMI. I can hear screeching and buzzing coming through speakers when connected, and it gets louder when GPU is being utilized (like in a game)